# Live click event

Tags: jquery

Can someone point out to me how to make the ask class into a live click event.

```
$('.ask').jConfirmAction( {
    question : "Are you sure you want to delete the selected row?", 
    yesAnswer : "Yes", 
    cancelAnswer : "No", 
    onYes: function(evt) { 
      contentpages(evt.target); 
    }
});
```

Unless its on this page:

```
 /*
 * jQuery Plugin : jConfirmAction
 * 
 * by Hidayat Sagita
 * http://www.webstuffshare.com
 * Licensed Under GPL version 2 license.
 *
 */
(function($){

jQuery.fn.jConfirmAction = function (options) {
    var theOptions = jQuery.extend( {
        question: "Are You Sure ?",
        yesAnswer: "Yes",
        cancelAnswer: "Cancel",
        questionClass: "question",
        yesClass: "yes",
        cancelClass: "no",
        onYes: function() {}   // for specifying a function to call when the "yes" button is clicked
    }, options );

    return this.each( function() {

        $(this).bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if($(this).next('.' + theOptions.questionClass).length <= 0) {
                $(this).after('<div class="' + theOptions.questionClass + '">'+theOptions.question+'<br/><span class="' + theOptions.yesClass + '">'+theOptions.yesAnswer+'</span><span class="' + theOptions.cancelClass + '">'+theOptions.cancelAnswer+'</span></div>');

                $( '.' + theOptions.yesClass ).bind('click', function( evt ) {
                    theOptions.onYes( evt );
                    $(this).parents( '.' + theOptions.questionClass ).fadeOut( 300, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    } );
                });

                $( '.' + theOptions.cancelClass ).bind('click', function(){
                    $(this).parents( '.' + theOptions.questionClass ).fadeOut( 300, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    } );
                });
            }

            $(this).next( '.' + theOptions.questionClass ).animate( { opacity: 1 }, 300 );
        });

    } );
}

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to change the code for the plugin simply initialise it after you put ".ask" elements in the page. e.g.

```
$("<div class='ask'>Ask me</div>").appendTo(".container").jConfirmAction({...});
```

If you want the plugin to register events on non existant elements you need to modify it to take a selector name as a parameter and generally registering the live event - this is a quick and dirty way

```
/*
 * jQuery Plugin : jConfirmAction
 * 
 * by Hidayat Sagita
 * http://www.webstuffshare.com
 * Licensed Under GPL version 2 license.
 *
 */
(function($){

 $.extend({
        jConfirmAction: function (options) {
                // Some jConfirmAction options (limited to customize language) :
        // question : a text for your question.
        // yesAnswer : a text for Yes answer.
        // cancelAnswer : a text for Cancel/No answer.
        var theOptions = jQuery.extend ({
            question: "Are You Sure ?",
            yesAnswer: "Yes",
            cancelAnswer: "Cancel",
            targetSelector : ".sample_selector"
        }, options);


            $(theOptions.targetSelector).live('click', function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                thisHref    = $(this).attr('href');

                if($(this).next('.question').length <= 0)
                    $(this).after('<div class="question">'+theOptions.question+'<br/> <span class="yes">'+theOptions.yesAnswer+'</span><span class="cancel">'+theOptions.cancelAnswer+'</span></div>');

                $(this).next('.question').animate({opacity: 1}, 300);

                $('.yes').bind('click', function(){
                    window.location = thisHref;
                });

                $('.cancel').bind('click', function(){
                    $(this).parents('.question').fadeOut(300, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                });

            });
        }
    });




})(jQuery);
```

and you initialise it like so

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    //specify what selector you want - all the other options still work     
    $.jConfirmAction({targetSelector: ".sample_selector"});

//add an element
                $("<div class='sample_selector'>Ask me</div>").appendTo("#container");


        });
```

Comment: In order to prevent multiple handlers from being bound, on successive calls to `. jConfirmAction ()`, I would recommend using a namespaced click event, and `.die()` before `.live()`, like so: `$(this).die('click.jca').live('click.jca', function(e) {...}` otherwise, looks good to me. +1

Comment: I tried $(this).live('click', function(e) {...}
 and that didn't do anything. It doesn't even bring up the ask question now with it like that.

Comment: try initialising it after adding the element as per first par of my answer

Comment: That's a little confusing. Let me do a jfiddle and show you what I have going on.

Comment: You are right this will not work simply because it needs the element to initialise (otherwise the loop over the element plugin is attached to never fires), so the only option you have is to simply initialise it when you add the element. OR you can modify the plugin to take a class as an argument and get rid of the each loop. Frankly I do not see a reason to do it any other way...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/g7Jwh/   If you notice if you go to page 2 and try and click on the delete icon it won't bring up the question on that page.

Comment: You are right this will not work simply because it needs the element to initialise (otherwise the loop over the element plugin is attached to never fires)

Comment: So what do I need to do to fix it so that it will fire the question pop up on any page other than page 1

Comment: you should initialise the plugin after you add an element to a page as specified in my answer. If you want to modify the plugin I added a quick and dirty way of modifying it - but simply init it after adding elements to the page